Need advice on fixing washing machine overflow!
(https://imgur.com/a/KsIn6vs)

older home with 1.5” copper piping

Laundry ties into kitchen drain

overflows from washing machine within 10-20 seconds

Can withstand full pressure from outdoor hose for more than a minute before slowly overflowing. Will drain if allowed at a lower rate.


Have had multiple plumbers out who do not know what issue is. They’ve tried snaking but had trouble getting past the “T” elbow”.
Any advice or insight would be deeply appreciated thank you.

Try the garden hose at the kitchen sink.  If the same, then the clog is pass the sink.

good idea, will try that. Thank you

If it doesn't have a cleanout it might be time to make some changes.

yeah unfortunately no cleanout that I am aware of. My plumber wanted to cut the vent and snake through there.

If the vent is easy to get at, cutting pipes is not that big of a job and might be the fastest way to clean the clog.

Do you have a cleanout outside?   I had the very same problem. The issue was a partial clog in the main drain line just outside the house.  Of course my laundry was closer to the clog than the kitchen was.

I would buy a jetter for a pressure washer on amazon for 40-50.00 stick in hit the pressure washer.

Running a camera down the pipe if you can (maybe at cut at vent) might help clarify this and other possible issues (unless the drain line is the 1.5" pipe).
